# Jpeg from server is corrupted

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, jpeg

I have a server which receives images and sends them to the clients. The problem is that whenever I send the image from the iPad, the image gets corrupted, but if I send it from the simulator, it doesn't. On `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` I used a compression of 0.2, but it still is corrupted.

I even tried this method (that didn't work):

```
- (BOOL)isJPEGValid:(NSData *)jpeg {
    if ([jpeg length] < 4) return NO;
    const char * bytes = (const char *)[jpeg bytes];
    if (bytes[0] != 0xFF || bytes[1] != 0xD8) return NO;
    if (bytes[[jpeg length] - 2] != 0xFF || bytes[[jpeg length] - 1] != 0xD9) return NO;
    return YES;
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Has anyone got any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the server software there is often a size restriction.  If the image you are sending will be naturally larger on an iPad than an iPhone, this could be the problem.

To test if this is the case, try shrinking the image in half then sending that `JPEGRep` to the server. (good luck, these are tricky ones to chase down)

Comment: The thing is that if I send the image from the simulator, the image is not corrupted, but if I do the opposite, then it is. So I don't think that shrinking the image would be a good choice. Also, the image must not be shrank as the user will see it all blurry

Comment: making the image smaller is a testing mechanism, to determine if the server might be having size issues.  also when having the same problem before, i've uploaded an image from the app that is identical (loaded as a resource) and see if all devices behave similarly